# How do I use System.IO to use ListView to show folders/Files on xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

So this is a follow up to a previous question I asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351971/i-am-trying-to-list-and-open-folders-in-visual-studio-xamarin-android?noredirect=1#comment106827689_60351971)

After following Jasons advice, I did a little resurch to use System.IO to use a listview to show folders on android.

I have the following example from the microsoft website...

```
    class PublicListViews : ListActivity
{
    public string ListCreate(string path)
    {

        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, countries);

        ListView.TextFilterEnabled = true;

        ListView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application, ((TextView)args.View).Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };
        return path;
    }
}
```

From what I understand this line....(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, countries); will use the list_item.xml in the resourses folder in the android project and countries is an array on countries that will be listed.

And I have also found the following code to get the directories and files...

```
        public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory.
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here.
    public static void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);
    }
```

Could anyone help me on the implementation of listing the folders/files using the ListAdaptor, and how to call it via the MainPage.xaml?

Mark.

Comment: shouldn't `ProcessDirectory` return a list or array of paths to display?

Comment: @Jason,This line (this, Resource.Layout.list_item, countries); uses the xml file in the android project, I would like to point it to an xml file in the FileBrowser project... I am not sure how to implement it correctly, any example to help me understand it more clearly would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have no idea what the "FileBrowser" project is.

Comment: @Jason, Thank you for your reply, sorry if I was not explanitary enough, its not my strong point :-), the FileBrowser is the main project, and the others are FileBrowser.android and FileBrowse.iOS, I created this project using the steps from James Montimagno [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0D3JIYFljE).

Comment: that means this is a Xamarin Forms project?  Your question is tagged Android, not Forms, and the code sample you posted is for Android only, and your question title specifically mentions Android.

Comment: @Jason, Terribly sorry for any confusion, As mensioned I am new to this and I do not have the correct way of explaining myself +terminology, or fully know the differences as of yet, this is a lesson on its own and I thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I guess that you want to get files from a folder, then display these files path in ListView in xamarin.android? Am I right?

If yes, I create simple that you can take a look:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/listView1"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="get files" android:id="@+id/button1"/>
</LinearLayout>

 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private ListView listview1;
    private Button button1;
    private List<string> files;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        listview1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        files = new List<string>();
        button1.Click += delegate
          {
              getpermission();
              //var targetdic = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/testfolder";
              var targetdic = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "testfolder";
              if(Directory.Exists(targetdic))
              {
                  files = DirSearch(targetdic);

                  listview1.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, files);

                  listview1.ItemClick += (s, e) =>
                  {
                      var t = files[e.Position];
                      Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Long).Show();
                  };
              }

          };
    }

    private void getpermission()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {

            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);
            return;
        }
    }

    private List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        List<string> folders = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
            {
                folders.Add(f);
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                folders.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {

        }

        return folders;
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Please don't forget to request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: Awsome! Thank you for this sample, I will have a play later on and I will let you know :-)

Comment: Pn this line  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main); am I supposed to have by default an activity_main file in the Resourses.Layout folder? Also, on the <LinearLayout tag I get "Tag was not closed", am I doing sometrhing wrong?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I have modify my code for you, you can also download my sample to test at github:https://github.com/CherryBu/foldersample

Comment: Bu, Great work, now I will set this as answerd, I understand and have learned what I needed to do, from this I can now follow the code and see what it is doing and how it is called woohoo :-) I also see how the permissions are setup in the manifest file this i also something i was unsure of, Thanx a bunch. So if its not to much bother can I ask one more question to clarify something for my we brain, at the SetContentView, is it possible to point this to another project.layout.somefile.xml?